# How enumerate folders and files in a SharePoint folder on Windows XP versus Windows 7

Tags: c#, sharepoint, windows-7, io, webdav

On Windows 7 I can access a SharePoint folder from Windows Explorer using the following path:

> \\host@port\DavWWWRoot\Folder\

Using the System.IO.Directory class (.Net 4.0 SP1), I can enumerate all directories and files for the same path as follows:

string path = @"\\myhost@myport\DavWWWRoot\MyFolder"

```
foreach (string dir in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path))
{
    // Do something
}

foreach (string filename in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path))
{
    // Do something
}
```

The above does not work for me on Windows XP - both Windows Explorer and the System.IO.Directory class do not appear to work for the same path. On Windows 7 `Directory.Exists(path)` returns `true`. On Windows XP it returns `false`.

Should I be using a different syntax for the path on Windows XP?

Answer (score 1):

Built-in support for WebDAV in XP is very limited (if exists at all), so it's a good idea to use a specialized WebDAV client component.